# What is the right way to do command grouping in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to group few bash instructions after a condition:

First attempt:

```
$ [[ 0 == 1 ]] && echo 1; echo 2
2
```

Second attempt:

```
$ [[ 0 == 1 ]] && (echo 1; echo 2)
$ [[ 0 == 0 ]] && (echo 1; echo 2)
1
2
```

So the latter is what I want.

Question: This is the 1st time I'm using `(`...`)` syntax in bash. Is `(`...`)` the right way to go, or does it have some side effects I might be missing?

Comment: Use `{ command1; command2; command3; }` which is a compound command rather than a sub-process. Note final semi-colon.

Comment: and the leading space (or other character of IFS)

Comment: You are probably better off using a proper `if` statement. `if [[ 0 == 1 ]]; then echo 1; echo 2; fi`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Placing commands in `()` **creates a subshell** in which the grouped commands are executed. That means that any changes to variables made in subshell, stay in subshell, for example

```
$ n=5; [[ "$n" == "5" ]] && ( ((n++)); echo $n); echo $n
6
5
```

Instead you want to group with `{}` which doesn't invoke a subshell. Then the output would be

```
$ n=5; [[ "$n" == "5" ]] && { ((n++)); echo $n; }; echo $n
6
6
```

Also mind the spaces on the inside of `{}` and semicolons: `{ ((n++)); echo $n; };`.

Comment: They can do the first example though and it clearly would work

Comment: Hm, indeed... :D

Comment: A good argument against subshells as default grouping method is that variable modification inside subshells are local to that subshell, i.e. `n=0; ( ((n++)); echo $n); echo $n` will print 1 (inside subshell) then 0 (outside subshell)`

Comment: That was the example I was trying to do but manager disturbed while I was typing and forgot what I wanted to do...